# NSDatePicker commits subfield changes on a timer

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdatepicker

I'm using a plain `NSDatePicker` control with `NSYearMonthDayDatePickerElementFlag`. It's the same as the date picker on the "date & time settings" panel with `MM/DD/YYYY` fields (the text box with 3 subfields, not the calendar portion). My users are getting stuck typing the digits into the year sub-field (though the behavior is present on the month and day fields too).

You can reproduce the problem using the Date & Time settings panel. Uncheck "Set date & time automatically" and click on the current year part of the field, 2014. Now just type 19 and pause. After about 1 second it fires some event and changes the date to 1969.

My users don't seem to type as fast as the `NSDatePicker` expects them to. Some event fires, calling some internal function `NSDatePickerCell(NSTextFieldWithStepperDatePickerInternal)_userEditExpired:`, well before many of my users can finish entering the 4 digit year. The timeout is reset after each keystroke, and seems about a second or a little less.

Does anybody know of a way to defeat that behavior without resorting to writing a whole new date picker? I'd be happy with a way to just change the timeout to something longer, maybe about 5 seconds, so the slower typists can get all 4 digits entered without the event firing and accepting their input before they're finished.

Comment: 5 years later: I'm having the exact same problem with the `NSDatePicker` in XCode 10.1.

Comment: The problem is still there. Looking for a solution too.